# Can a billiard rack be a square, for every number of balls?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, circle-packing

A [billiard rack](https://i-bosity-com.oss-cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/product_img/264/54030713/54030713_10_image.jpg?x-oss-process=image/resize,p_100/watermark,image_d2F0ZXJtYXJrX2ltZy8xNzExMTQwNy9kZWZhdWx0LnBuZz94LW9zcy1wcm9jZXNzPWltYWdlL3Jlc2l6ZSxQXzk5,g_nw,x_0,y_0) is a rack, usually a triangle, that can hold a certain number of equal size billiard balls, such that the balls' centres cannot move within the rack.

Can the rack be a square, for every number of balls? (For 1 to 25 balls, the answer is [yes](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/rigid/).)

Comment: There is something I don't understand. I'm really naive, but if you do it for n balls, can't you also do it for 4n balls? I mean why the 8 ball rack is not 4 times the 4 ball rack??

Comment: @MarsaultChabat: I think the pictures in the link try to *maximize* the size of the square, hence the "new" construction for $n=8$.

Comment: You mean maximize the size of the balls for a fix sqare? Ok I see, then if in your question you don't put a size condition it seem's that the answer is yes (since every nummber is equal to something smaller than 24 modulo 4). But I can gess that you want more so I have no idea :)

Comment: @MarsaultChabat The link shows that for $1\le n \le 24$ there exists a square that can hold $n$ balls so that their centres cannot move. (The link also shows the supposed maximum size square for each case, but I'm not concerned with that.)

Comment: @MarsaultChabat There exists a square rack that can hold 8 balls, so there exists a square rack that can hold 32 balls, but I'm not sure if there's a square rack that can hold 31 balls. If you just remove one ball from the rack with 32 balls, then the other balls are free to move.

Comment: Is even this multiplying by 4 statement obvious? I don't see what the scaling procedure is (certainly trying to place 4 copies of the n rack in a square might not work, since there are no longer 4 sides holding the smaller n-ball configurations...)

Comment: @RonniePavlov I can see how it's true for some specific cases, but it is not obvious to me why it would be true in general.

Comment: @RonniePavlov Just keep gluing mirror images. Balls at a (to be removed) inner edge are then prevented to move into a neighboring square by their mirror image.

Comment: It's worth clarifying that "the balls' centres cannot move within the rack" means that motion is impossible *even if the balls move simultaneously*. This is different from saying that [no individual ball can be moved without disturbing other balls](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RigidCirclePacking.html).

Comment: @JoachimKönig Gluing mirror images does not always result in a rigid structure. For example, if you take the 2 ball rack, there are two ways to glue mirror images: one produces a sort of X formation, the other produces a sort of ring. In the X-formation, the balls can move (just rotate the 4 balls in the centre about their collective centre). In the ring formation, the balls can move (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4611295/five-circles-in-a-rectangle-can-the-circles-move/4611296#4611296) for an explanation of a similar fact).

Comment: @TimothyChow That's indeed a useful clarification, I was implicitly assuming the "individual movement impossible" scenario. In that case, I retract my above comment.